# New account for minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am confused, do i have to pay 30$ for a new MC account if it is already on my computer? I am wondering because me and my sibling share the current account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share the same account onto multiple PCs, but [only one person can be logged in at one time](http://minemum.com/FAQ).  If someone else logs-in on the same account, they will be able to still play Single Player (No LAN), but cannot join any multiplayer sessions. (This includes opening your Single Player world to LAN; the other player will not be able to access the "server" since the host and the person joining are the same account).